# JSF and Primefaces graphicImage rendered attribute changes but nothing happens

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I've a problem that I can't find any solutions for. I'm using `JSF 2.1` and `primefaces`, and I have a bean that contains a boolean variable with a getter and setter. I use `p:ajax` to call a method that updates the boolean value when `p:graphicImage` is updated.

During debugging this work correctly; `p:graphicImage` has the attribute rendered set to the boolean variable of the bean. When the image is updated by ajax however, the getter is called and returns the correct value, true, but image is not rendered!

This is my code:

```
<p:panel>
    <p:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">
        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{msg.username}"></p:outputLabel>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:inputText id="username" value="#{user.userName}">
                    <p:ajax listener="#{registationController.checkUserName}" event="blur" update="imgControl"/>
                </h:inputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column id="imgControl">
                <p:graphicImage 
                        value="/resources/images/#{registationController.userNameAvailable}"
                        height="24px"  rendered="#{registationController.imgShow}"/>

            </p:column>
            <p:message for="username" id="msgUsername" severity="info"></p:message>
        </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
```

And this is the bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="registationController")
public class RegistrationController implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1086976296682850824L;
@ManagedProperty(value="#{user}")
private User usr;
private MyLogger log;
private String userNameAvailable=null;
private boolean imgShow=false;

public void checkUserName(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
    User tempUser=null;

    UserDAOImpl userDAOImpl=new UserDAOImpl();
    if(usr.getUserName()!="" && usr.getUserName()!=null){
        tempUser=userDAOImpl.selectUserByUsername(usr.getUserName());
        imgShow=true;
    } else {
        imgShow=false;
    }
    if(tempUser!=null){
        userNameAvailable="no.png";

    } else{
        userNameAvailable= "yes.png";
    }
}
public boolean isImgShow() {
    return imgShow;
}
others methods...
}
```

Any ideas why this doesn't works?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Did you try to remove `px` from `height` attribute? Just leave `24`.

Comment: I tried, but nothing changes

Comment: I realized that, debugging, the getter is called 3 times (and I don't understand why) and always returns the right value...

Comment: I modified the bean scope to Session and now it's working only if I refresh the page... How to do to render the component without reload?

Comment: What happens if you move the `id="imgControl"` from the `p:column` tag to the `p:graphicImage` tag?

Comment: nothing happens, it's the same..

Comment: summary: the rendered value is set correctly, but image becomes visible or invisible only when I refresh the page. Instead if the image is visible, the image changes dynamically whitout refresh... only rendered attribute is not dynamically updates, but I need to refresh... how to avoid that?

Comment: @Follo486 What browser are you experiencing this in?

Comment: I test this on chrome firefox and IE.

Comment: New day and new problem. no code changes from last time, but now also for change images I have to reload, it's not immediate. I'm really going crazy!

Comment: I realized that if I put the id in graphicImage the image changes but if it is in <p:column> no. However for change visibility I've to refresh, like before.

Comment: I've found a partial solution... if I render the entire form writing '<p:ajax listener="..." update="@form">' it's work correctly but render all components in the form...

Comment: I've found the solution for this problem. I've simply miss to add the JSTL libraries  in my project. Now work correctly without reload the page. Thank to all.